# How do I properly add an "or" clause to a php snippet?

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have this php snippet in a WordPress-based website:

```
if ( ! is_singular( 'page' ) || ! current_theme_supports( 'genesis-after-entry-widget-area' ) ) {
    return;
}
```

I would like to have some type of "or" clause, where I can tell the server, "if this item is a **page** *or* a **portfolio** type, then return."

Basically, would like to include the types:  "page" and "portfolio" in this snippet.

But I am unsure how to do this without redeclaring the function all over again.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think what are you looking for is WordPress `get_post_type` function:

```
if (get_post_type() == 'page' || get_post_type() == 'portfolio') {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tuananh.  The is_singular works when I insert either page or portfolio there, but it only works for one or the other; I want it to work with both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a wordpress developer, but based on their [`is_singular` documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular), it seems that the function accepts an array of custom post type values.  So you should be able to do something like this:

```
if (is_singular(array('page', 'portfolio'))) {
    return;
}
```